# Get items by date range for monogodump when date field is stored in ISO

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection I am trying to dump out within a date range. I've got a query working for ALL rows, and also have it working with $date: 1058715 (numerical) but that never outputs anything I'm guessing because it doesn't match any rows in that conditional.

My dates in monog are stored as ISODATE(yadayada), so can I still query with $date: (numerical value)?

I created a date in the shell and got its value then using that numerical value.

Heres my working query , which outputs no rows

```
sudo bin/mongodump --db myDB --collection myColl -q '{"reading_date" : { "$gte" : { $date:1341230400000}}}' --out - > dump/myDB /will.bson
```

But I think I need

```
sudo bin/mongodump --db myDB --collection myColl -q '{"reading_date" : { "$gte" : new Date(2012,05,01)}}' --out - > dump/myDB /will.bson
```

Comment: So does your second query work as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are storing a date, you can compare it to javascript date in the mongo shell like this:

`db.coll.find({mydate:{$gt:new Date(2012,0,1)}})`

Note that in js months are zero-based so the above represents January 1st 2012.

Since you need to pass this to mongodump, use this syntax instead:

```
mongodump -q '{mydate:{$gte:Date(1341230400000)}}'
```

Reference: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON

Comment: I need to do it outside the Shell

Comment: There is a syntax error in that second example. If you add curly braces, there needs to be a key for the value. otherwise you get `assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting ':': offset:21`