# mongodb mongodump json parse error on date field

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb

I have this query, which generates 10340 Failure parsing JSON string near: my_da error. If I change the conditioanal from reading_Date to another field with a baisc match, it works. There something going on when it parses the JSON date..

sudo bin/mongodump --db myDB --collection myColl -q "{my_date: {$gte: {Date(1341230400000)}}}" --out - > dump/myDB/will.bson

Could someone lend a hand?

The reading_date is stored in ISODate format as: "my_date" : ISODate("2011-08-31T12:00:00Z")

Thanks!

Comment: didn't I just answer this question here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788708/get-items-by-date-range-for-monogodump-when-date-field-is-stored-in-iso/11789018#11789018

Comment: didnt c u changed question...

Comment: I don't know what that means - what is "changed question"?  Anyway, try the answer I provided there.  The answer posted here is not correct, as you already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ mkdir dump
$ mongodump -d myDB -c myColl -q "{my_date: {\$gte: { \$date: 1341230400000 } }}" -o dump/
```

$date is the JSON representation of a 64 bit signed integer for milliseconds since epoch (unsigned before version 1.9.1).
[Mongo Extended JSON](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON)

Also the operator $ was escaped